Azure API management create/update policy
We are migrating a release pipeline from Azure built in release to a YAML code based pipeline. This has gone well until we started looking at API management. We've managed to import the OpenAPI endpoints using az apim import but are struggling to find a solution to import the policies.
The old release pipeline used the Set-AzApiManagementPolicy function but we are keen to move away from this. As a side note we did try to use this but it moans about having to login with Connect-AzAccount. The first call is being made in an AzureCli@2 task without the Connect-AzAccount call. The old release works okay and creates the policy.
Looking at this github issue it implies that az apim will be extended to support policies but as far as we are aware this hasn't happened yet.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14695
The issue also talks about using the REST endpoint to update the policy which seems to be a good half way house. Details of the rest API are here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/policy/create-or-update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP
Although that article seems to miss out the apis parameter included in the earlier issue report.
So we've configured the url including the apis parameter and are using az rest --method put to issue the request. A simple policy body is defined as:
$xml = "<policies><inbound/><backend><forward-request/></backend><outbound/></policies>" | Out-String
$body='{"properties":{"format":"xml","value":"' + $xml + '"}}' | Out-String
$body=$body.Replace('"','\"') | Out-String

So our az rest call is:
az rest --method PUT --uri $uri --body $body

When issued this generates the following error:
az : < was unexpected at this time.
At C:\Data\apims1.ps1:11 char:1
+ az rest --method PUT --uri $uri --body $body
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (< was unexpected at this time.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

If we revise the body to not include the xml as in:
$body='{"properties":{"format":"xml","value":""}}' | Out-String
$body=$body.Replace('"','\"') | Out-String

It raises the following error which implies it is expecting xml as it cannot find the root element:
az : ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"ValidationError","message":"One or more fields contain incorrect values:","details":[{"code":"ValidationError","target":"representation","message":"Root element is missing."}]}})
At C:\Data\apims1.ps1:11 char:1
+ az rest --method PUT --uri $uri --body $body
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Bad Requ... missing."}]}}):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

We have tried encoding the < and > using ampersand lt/gt and also ampersand # 60/62 ; with other errors being reported.
Any help is greatly appreciated to resolve this issue. TIA

I struggled with az rest too but I think you shouldn't have such issues with Invoke-RestMethod. Try this:
$accessToken = (az account get-access-token | ConvertFrom-Json).accessToken
$headers = @{Authorization="Bearer $accessToken"}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $uri -Body $body -Headers $headers

